# The data which jquery $.ajax function return could not be parse to json

Tags: string, json, jquery

I have a file called "config.json" which have

```
{
    "book": {
        "config": {
            "uuid": "81393fe88f7c4e5a98070905790b39e1",
            "type": "fullscreen",
            "size": "1024,768"
                  }
             }
}
```

then I use $.ajax to read this file,

```
    $.ajax({
        url:...,
        data:{...},
        type:"get",
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data, textStatus){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

but the data return is string format like:

```
"{\n "book": {\n ... }\n }\n }\n}"
```

then I want parse the data into json,but all the parse function couldn't work,

```
var obj=$.parseJSON(data);
```

but the result is "null"

then I want use "jquery.json-2.3.js"

```
console.log(data.toJSON());
```

but the result is `data.toJSON is not a function`

How can I solve this problem?parse the string to json

Comment: what about data.replace("\n", ""); and then use toJSON ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery automatically parses  the response if you specify the dataType so calling

```
var obj=$.parseJSON(data);
```

returns an error

Answer (score 1):

jQuery automatically evaluates the JSON to an object if `dataType: 'json'` (assuming it's a valid JSON format, which your data above is). So re-evaluating an object to object again doesn't make any sense.

If you want JSON string from the server, just set `dataType` to `html`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with *JSON.parse(data)*?

Also getting rid of the \n by doing a replace with an empty string will help I think.