# Jquery Ajax won't return the data (parse error), but Postman succeeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, go

I've been using Postman to test my REST API (written in Go). Now is the moment of truth, connecting to the front end and I've hit a hiccup. I'm using jQuery.ajax to send a GET to my server, which should then send me back the response.

**Note**: Going to postman and sending a GET request to `http://REMOTE_IP:8000/users/` returns the information I'm looking for, an array of User objects (JSON). It confuses me that it would work for Postman, but not jQuery.

## jQuery Get

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://REMOTE_IP:8000/users/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

## Go Backend

```
func GetUsersRoute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var queryResult []models.User

    queryErr := Config.Users.Find(bson.M{}).All(&queryResult)
    resultsJSON, jsonErr := json.Marshal(queryResult)

    handleQueryAndJsonErrors(w, queryErr, jsonErr)

    // added these for cors, not sure they do anything helpful
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*")

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(resultsJSON)
}
```

I also have a logger attached to my go backend, and here are the request method and request URI that are printed out when I make the request:

```
GET /users?callback=jQuery223019655483671137586_1461946990647&_=1461946990648
```

Here are some articles I found useful:
[The data which jquery $.ajax function return could not be parse to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120904/the-data-which-jquery-ajax-function-return-could-not-be-parse-to-json)

https://github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/blob/master/cors/cors.go

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Here are the errors returned with jQuery's err callback:
[image]

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Your datatype for your ajax call is jsonp?  Are you intending to do that?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `jsonp` instead of `json` as datatype? jsonp expects a callback to be fired and, as far as I can see, neither your client nor your server sides are ready to handle that. Perhaps you just need to perform a regular post request using **json** as datatype instead or are you trying to avoid cross-domain issues?

Comment: Perhaps you should check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036365/how-should-a-jsonp-response-be-formed-in-go-using-http-responsewriter

Comment: The reason I use jsonp is because of CORS. I get '.. response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin REMOTE_IP ...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### # Answer

I found a nice go library that handles the cross-origin problems I was having, meaning I didn't have to rely on jsonp. Here's the revised go code:

#### Using the CORS Handler

```
handler := cors.Default().Handler(r)
err := http.ListenAndServe(port, handler)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

#### Revised handler

```
func GetUsersRoute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var queryResult []models.User

    queryErr := Config.Users.Find(bson.M{}).All(&queryResult)
    resultsJSON, jsonErr := json.Marshal(queryResult)

    handleQueryAndJsonErrors(w, queryErr, jsonErr)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(resultsJSON)
}
```

#### Calling from the frontend

```
var extension = 'users/',
    requestPath = serverAddress + extension;

$.ajax({
    url: requestPath,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: successCall,
    error: failCall
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your server can handle JSONP requests by using following tests.

```
http://REMOTE_IP:8000/users?callback=myFunction
```

The response instead of this (it will look like this if it doesn't support JSONP):

```
{ "thing": "value" .... }
```

Should look like this (again, if it supports JSONP):

```
myFunction({ "thing": "value" .... });
```